# Azure Kubernetes Private Key Location

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I've used this command to deploy a Kubernetes cluster in Azure:

```
az acs create -n acs-cluster -g acsrg1 -d applink789 --generate-ssh-keys
```

Everything is working- I can connect to the cluster with `kubectl`.  Now I want to define an SSH step in a Continuous Delivery pipeline.  The documentation indicates that this command created a public/private key pair.  Where is the private key stored?  I've looked in the .ssh, .kube, and .azure folders in my home directory but I can't tell if any of those values are the private key.

Comment: please add the platform you're running on (win/lin)

Comment: Windows 10 client accessing a Linux cluster in Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out- the documentation says the keys will be generated *if they are missing.*  If the id_rsa keypair is present in the `.ssh` hidden directory, it is used.  Connected with Putty using the `azureuser` default account.